# ASP.NET Core Web API + Keycloak Authorization + Excel or PowerBI OData feed organisational account

Tags: excel, powerbi, asp.net-core-webapi, keycloak

We have developed set of OData APIs and for authorization, we are using Keycloak.

We want to call that API in OData feed with an organisational account.

We tried to authorize API with OData feed organisational account with Azure AD and we are able to get the POP up of Azure AD, but we are not sure how to do with Keycloak.

Does anyone have an idea how to do setup Keycloak AD POP up in Excel OData feed with an organisational account?